# How to prevent IIS7 for handling HTTP status code 401?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, exception, http-status-code-401

I'm working my ASP.NET MVC 2 project. I create exception filter for catching unauthorized access exception that occur when user does not has permission to view some action.

```
[CustomError(typeof(UnauthorizedAccessException), "Error", "UnauthorizedAccess")]
public class MyController : BaseController
{
}
```

After exception has been thrown, my filter will transfer to configured controller/action that is the following method.

```
public ActionResult UnauthorizedAccess(ExceptionContext context)
{
    Response.StatusCode = CustomHttpStatusCode.UnauthorizedUser;

    return View(model);
}
```

Finally, before ASP.NET application end this request, it will call the following method that located in Global.ascx for changing custom HTTP status code to HTTP status 401(unauthorized access).

```
public void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Response.StatusCode == CustomHttpStatusCode.UnauthorizedUser)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 401;
    }
}
```

Everything is work fine on my machine (IIS 7.5). But it does not work on my deploy website. It still return plain text **"You do not have permission to view this directory or page."** instead of my custom error page.

PS. The following config is my current web.config for this case.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="On"></customErrors>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
         <remove statusCode="502" subStatusCode="-1" />
         <remove statusCode="501" subStatusCode="-1" />
         <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
         <remove statusCode="412" subStatusCode="-1" />
         <remove statusCode="406" subStatusCode="-1" />
         <remove statusCode="405" subStatusCode="-1" />
         <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
         <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
         <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />
      </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: Even I change to return status code to 403 if current user is authenticated but the result still the same.

Answer (score 16):

You can pass through IIS7 default error messages in two ways

One is to set response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors to be true

```
response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
response.Status = response.Status;
```

For some reason, TrySkipIisCustomErrors is not honoured if you don't set response.Status.

The other is to set existingResponse to "PassThrough" in web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But this will ignore all set IIS custom error pages.

Comment: `<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />` did the trick for me, thanks! I did not need to use `TrySkipIisCustomErrors`

Answer (score 14):

I just found easy solution for this problem. I just add new setting in to web.config file like the following code. Everything works fine on my deployment website.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration> 
    <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="PassThrough">
          <remove statusCode="502" subStatusCode="-1" />
          <remove statusCode="501" subStatusCode="-1" />
          <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
          <remove statusCode="412" subStatusCode="-1" />
          <remove statusCode="406" subStatusCode="-1" />
          <remove statusCode="405" subStatusCode="-1" />
          <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
          <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
          <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />
      </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

So I can create custom error page both in plain text and JSON response too.

For more information: [HttpErrorsSection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690576(VS.90).aspx)

PS. But I cannot found **existingResponse** attribute in Error Pages feature of IIS manager.

Comment: There are quite a few IIS settings such as `existingResponse` that aren't surfaced in IIS Manager. A good example of this is if you try to revert custom error settings to use inherited values: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255120