# Azure Handle custom HTTP 401

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a web service with basic auth (via custom database check in code) that returns HTTP 401 + SOAP FAULT message when user credentials are wrong. This works in my local IIS 7 but not in Azure...

When I move it to Azure, via App Service, and I insert bad credentials, I always get the following message:

```
HTTP 401 
"You do not have permission to view this directory or page.".
```

But I want my custom error message in SOAP Fault format!

After hours of research I have found that if my code returns a response with HTTP 401 status, Azure translate this to the end-user like the message above, ignoring my custom error message.

I made another example with a "hello world" SOAP endpoint:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return "Hello world";
    }
```

In my local IIS I got HTTP 401 "Hello world", but when I deploy this to Azure I got the same "Yout do not have permissions..."

**¿How can I disable/avoid/dodge Azure 401 message transformation and return my own custom error message (SOAP FAULT)?**

Note: I've already tried to disable authentication in Azure app service, enabling with "allow anonymous requests", etc.

**Solution**

The problem was in IIS. Adding the following line to my web.config works.

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47307706/3763467

I will keep the same title/tags for other people facing the same problem and thinks the problem is in Azure.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your web.config file might be setup to have custom errors turned on.

Can you please check your web.config file and set customer errors to on?

```
<customErrors="off" />
```

Comment: Hi, I have updated with the solution, but this helped me to find the problem too, thx.